# Android MediaPlayer Error (100,0)

Tags: android, media-player

i have the next problem:
I need to play a sound 6 times in 6 seconds, if i touch a button it will reproduce it again. My app was working well until I test it in a Nexus 5. 
After some repetitions appears in the LogCat: 
MediaPlayer error(100,0)
MediaPlayer Error(100,0)
and crashes.

I read in the forum that maybe the problem was because the mp3 is less than 1 second, but I test it with a mp3 bigger and the error persist.

Don't know how to fix it. Read the forums but there is not an answer

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985815/android-media-player-error-100-0 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33006900/how-to-solve-mediaplayer-error-100-0-in-nexus-5

Comment: That show how to catch the error, but i want to continue playing, not to stop de sound